# Bash loop using two input files as lists

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to optimize a for loop to download files from a website based in a file with SPECIES names and their corresponding numbers of ACCESSION.
I want the loop to work first with the first species and the first accession number of the each file and so on... I tried the basic rule but it is not working.

```
        #!/bin/sh
        #Load modules
        module load sra-toolkit/2.10.7-centos_linux64
```

Automatized download and assembly of transcritomes. SRA accession and species code required as arguments for the script

```
        WORKSPACE=/vto
        WORKSPACEFINAL=/vto
        SPECIES=${WORKSPACE}/species_names.txt
        ACCESSION=$accession_numers.txt

        for i in $SPECIES
            for j in $ACCESION
        do
        mkdir $SPECIES
        cd $SPECIES
```

#SRA download and processing.

```
        prefetch $ACCESSION

        fastq-dump --defline-seq '@$sn[_$rn]/$ri' --split-files       ${WORKSPACEFINAL}/ncbi/public/sra/${ACCESSION}.sra -O  ${ACCESSION} 
 

        done
```

Comment: why aren't you using $i and $j inside the loop?

Comment: sorry you are right!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have **two loops** and just **one done** and do you have that working?
And as @Mheni said it seems that you aren't using the loop's variables
Here an example of a simple script with two loops one inside the other

```
file_a=$(cat file_a.txt)
file_b=$(cat file_b.txt)

for i in $file_a
do

        for j in $file_b
        do
                printf "$i\n"
                printf "$j\n"
        done
#// if you add code here is outside j loop

done
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks specially for the patience with the new ones in programming!